# CoreData: fetch in background and ObjectIDs

Tags: core-data, ios7

For two core data entities A and B where A is having one to many relationships with B, I am trying to perform a fetch in background context whose parent is main context [associated with UI]. Since I need the results in a pre-fetch fashion i.e. core data must also populate relationships as shown below [using MagicalRecord]:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* bgContext = [NSManagedObjectContext context];

[bgContext performBlock:^{
    NSpredicate * searchPredicate = <some search criteria in entity A>
    if(!searchPredicate){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //completionBlock is a callback block to be executed on main thread.        completionBlock(nil);
            return;
        });
    }
    //Using below request to get relationship data in pre-fetch format.
    NSFetchRequest* aRequest = [A requestAllSortedBy:@"<aColumn>" ascending:YES withPredicate:searchPredicate inContext:bgContext];

    [aRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:YES];
    [aRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"photos"]];//photos is a relationship between A and B
    [aRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:YES];
    [aRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];




    NSArray *as = [A executeFetchRequest:aRequest inContext:bgContext];
    if (as == nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock(nil);
            return;
        });
    }
    NSArray *objectIDs =[as valueForKey:@"objectID"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext];
    [mainContext performBlock:^{

        //temporary bad solution
        NSMutableArray *entities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (A *a in as) {
            [entities addObject:[a inContext:mainContext]];
        }
        completionBlock([NSArray arrayWithArray:entities]);
    }];


}];
```

Though the results are coming as expected but still then I would like to know if above approach below the comment "//temporary bad solution" is an efficient one or not. 
Even if I pass objectIDs to main context then in that case how the relationship will be pre-fetched ?

Comment: Out of all of the results, how many need to be loaded into memory at any one time? Generally not more than 20, so always loading them all is not efficient.

Comment: Ok. If I set the batch size in above code still then also I need to loop over entire result in order to convert the nsmanagedobject's association with main context, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to fetch all of the managed object ids and pass those to the main thread. Then, as required on the main thread, batch load the managed objects from the object ids and cache the managed object instances (refresh them to turn them into faults but keep the managed objects if you get short on memory).